# Hilbert space problem of orthogonal space

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators, projection

could anyone help me with this problem. ¡Thankyou very much!

Let H be a Hilbert space.

(a) Let M be a closed subspace of H and let P be a orthogonal projection on M. Prove that P² = P and P is an self-adjoint operator.

(b) Let R ∈ L(H,H) and R²= R and R is self-adjoint. Prove M = Im(R) is a closed subspace of H. Prove that R is the orthogonal projection on M.

Comment: Where do you have troubles?

Comment: For a) is it enough to prove that  < P(v), v` > = < v, P(v`) > for v, v`∈ H with v = u + w, v`=u`+w` where u, u`∈ U and w, w` ∈ W  and U,W are orthogonal. ??

Comment: for (b) is it enough to prove that x = ( x - R(x) ) + R(x) then H = ker(R) ⊕ Im(R) to show that R is an orthogonal proyection??

Comment: and to show M is closed, I have prove that M = ker( I - R ) where I is the identity.

Comment: I don´t know if its right the steps I did.

Comment: solved! thankyou!